# How do I specify the MySQL sock file location for thinking sphinx?

Tags: mysql, thinking-sphinx

My socket file is located here:

```
/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

When I do:

```
rake thinking_sphinx:start
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I want to tell thinking_sphinx where my socket file is. How is this possible?  This issue appeared after performing a hard reboot of my slice on Slicehost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED to be (hopefully) clearer:

you can specify the mysql socket to be used in sphinx search's configuration file, [`sphinx.conf`](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#quick-tour), via [`sql_sock`](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-sock):

```
sql_sock = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(note that it depends on the [`sql_host`](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-host) setting whether this value will actually be used)

you can also use thinking_sphinx' configuration file, `RAILS_ROOT/config/sphinx.yml`, to set (overwrite) these values:

```
sql_sock: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: i don't really understand your answer

Answer (score 1):

In the version `1.3.20` the socket path can be defined via `database.yml`, e.g

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: app_name_development
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Now, `thinking-sphinx` will use the socket path => `/tmp/mysql.sock`.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting code snippet from the edge sphinx, which states that sphinx **requires** TCP connections.

From thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:

```
def connection
# If you use localhost, MySQL insists on a socket connection, but Sphinx
# requires a TCP connection. Using 127.0.0.1 fixes that.
address = searchd.address || '127.0.0.1'
address = '127.0.0.1' if address == 'localhost'

Mysql2::Client.new(
  :host  => address,
  :port  => searchd.mysql41,
  :flags => Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS
)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from ax does not work.

You can see from commit 49f467b25075666104a46b190139dd1bdbb1452f that someone's added support in SphinxHelper to set the socket. I haven't used this method, and don't have too much time to test it for you, so you're on your own with this method.

Also, curiously, in commit http://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/commit/a12dbd55ed9046faf6369a3d0aa452b75a31b5b6 it looks like they added support for sockets via your database.yml, however if you look at the current edge code, this seems to have been removed?

Short answer: symlink your actual mysqld.sock to the location sphinx is looking for it.